# Illustrator pen auto-correction on Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, pen-tool

Illustator has a nice effect on it pencil tool : curve auto-correction. When you draw line, it automatically correct your hand, making it more neat and round. Sadly, I don't see this option on the photoshop pencil tool.

And well, I can't /don't want use Illustrator for several reasons, including the fact it's not really suitable for drawing. I'm quite surprised don't found it on Photoshop, according to how usefull it is.

So there is my question : is there any plugin or way to benefit it on Photoshop ? Many thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Update CC 2018 (CC v.19) release

As of the latest version of Photoshop CC update there is now built-in smoothing on brush tools. On your main toolbar there's a Smoothing section and in your Brush settings is a new Smoothing option as well.

[image]

---

#### [Lazy Nezumi Pro](http://lazynezumi.com/) - 32€

Lazy Nezumi Pro is a Windows app that helps you draw smooth, beautiful lines, with your mouse or pen tablet.

- **Windows only**
- 30 day trial
- Plugin for Photoshop, but it is also a standalone app, that works with other applications besides Photoshop.

[image]

---

#### [Hej Stylus](http://hejstylus.com/) - 12€

Hej Stylus! is minimalistic menu bar application. It makes your cursor behave like a brush.The result is super precise cursor steering and stroke smoothing.

- **Mac only**
- One hour trial

[image]-----

#### [Sketchbook pro](https://www.sketchbook.com/desktop) - 4.99€/month or 29.99€/year

Standalone drawing application from Autodesk, that has a built in mouse smoothing called: [`Steady Stroke` <sup><sub>(Link to demonstration video)</sub></sup>](https://youtu.be/TkJoOaJ_P88)

- **Mac and Windows**
- 15 Day Trial

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try playing round with the free-form pen tool, once selected there is a control panel allowing some degree of 'curve fit' similar to correction.

Answer (score 0):

You're referring to **Smoothness** and **Fidelity** settings within Illustrator.

[image]

I'm unaware of any plug in which adds these options to Photoshop. Remember vector tools in Photoshop are not designed to be as robust as in an actual vector application, such as Illustrator.