# Drawing smoother lines in Photoshop CS2

Tags: adobe-photoshop, drawing, cs2

I've seen people draw in Adobe Photoshop, however unlike my sketchy lines, theirs come out a lot smoother and I mean a lot. I was just wondering how to do this and if its a system thing rather then a skills thing. If anyone can help my understanding that would be great.

Comment: can you add some screenshots with examples of smooth lines from other people and your own?

Comment: This is part skill, part settings and part tools. There are quite a lot related questions on stack already, such as this one: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/37839/illustrator-pen-auto-correction-on-photoshop

Answer (score 1):

1. Practice, practice, practice
2. A well configured brush
3. [A drawing tablet](http://www.wacom.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you do not mean fuzzy lines, but solid lines with smooth curvature:

By using Wacom or other high quality graphic tablet one gets perfect lines - but only if he or she has got what it takes to draw perfect lines by hand. He also can get good results by using an accurate high resolution mouse. I have seen those just in front of my eyes when a talented person worked with Photoshop. She drawed by Brush tool.

The rest of us get perfect lines by using paths - the Bezier curves. See the following example:[image]

Paths are clunky to use in Photoshop for drawing. They fit much better to making complex selections for example when removing backgrounds.

Adobe Illustrator is the industry standard tool for using paths in drawings.

Answer (score -1):

To draw smooth lines you must use smooth brush.

[image]

Also, you can use brush panel to modify brush as per requirement.