# Photoshop plugin for cleaning line drawings?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, drawing, drawing-tablet

I'm a drawing newbie, trying to get past stick figures using Photoshop and a Wacom tablet, and I'm even more horrendous than with pen and paper.

I found PS's brush smoothing capability, which helps reduce jaggies.  Is there anything out there that can help join lines cleanly?  I'm spending forever trying to avoid/fix the small overruns and underruns that dog those of us unencumbered with conspicuous talent.

[image]

Comment: Lazy Nezumi and other similar apps can help connect lines as well: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/37839/2332 I haven't tried the one in PS CC but at least Lazy Nezumi gives you more control. — I don't know if maybe you did have a sketch layer that is now hidden... but a sketch is something that really helps when you start making the clean line art.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware there is no such plug in or feature. I don't think any computer is aware enough to know what may or may not be a "mistake" or overshoot.

Comment: Al tough there are plugin tools to do this in illustrator after drawing them all. ;)

Answer (score 1):

In Photoshop you can make a selection which prevents overshoots, only selected area can be painted. That helps but it does not make you more accurate.  Making the selection needs good Photoshop skills.

You should paint different things to different layers. Then making the protective selection and possible fixing are easier.

My suggestion:

Goto Inkscape if you need fast results. Inkscape's freehand curve tool "the pencil" can be adjusted to smooth the curves as you draw and numerous snapping modes help to hit the endpoints exactly. In addition: All curves are freely editable separate objects. The following freehand drawing with a mouse took 10 seconds:

[image]

I had smoothing and snap to curve ON.

Do not forget to develop your fully freehand (no selections, no smoothing, no snapping) painting skills!!!!

Comment: While the snapping is fine i find that it does not work well when you work with tablet speeds. It works fine if you work slower, but then the tablets benefit is gone and slowing allows me to hit the target anyway.

Comment: @joojaa Right. A skilled tablet user do not need snaps nor smoothing. I have seen it. (Unfortunately not in a mirror)